# How to build a module and its submodules using maven reactor?

Tags: maven

I have a project with three levels of modules. Let's suppose it has the following organization ...

```
+-- maven-root
   +-- maven-module-1
   |   +-- maven-submodule-1-1
   |   +-- maven-submodule-1-2
   +-- maven-module-2
   |   +-- maven-submodule-2-1
   |   +-- maven-submodule-2-2
   +-- maven-module-3
       +-- maven-submodule-3-1
       +-- maven-submodule-3-2
```

Additionally, we have the following set of dependencies

- `maven-module-2` depends upon `maven-module-1`
- `maven-module-3` depends upon `maven-module-3`

In this structure, and supposing artifacts for `maven-module-1` and its submodules are already available in local repository, is there a solution using maven reactor (as an example) to build only `maven-module-2` and its submodules ?

I already know that, using maven reactor, if I do

```
mvn clean install -pl :maven-module-2 --also-make-dependant
```

It will build

1. maven-module-2
2. maven-submodule-2-1
3. maven-submodule-2-2
4. maven-module-3
5. maven-submodule-3-1
6. maven-submodule-3-2

as `maven-module-3` have a dependency upon `maven-module-2`

And obviously, running

```
mvn clean install -pl :maven-module-2 --also-make
```

will only build `maven-module-1` and `maven-module-2`.

So, how, using that project organization, can I build only `maven-module-2` ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Maybe Gradle can do it, but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using

```
mvn clean install -f maven-module-2 -N
```

will build only maven-module-2 and

```
mvn clean install -f maven-module-2
```

will build maven-module-2 and its children

Take care that -f is used to say to Maven to use another POM (or module directory and it takes the pom.xml in it) than the one in the current directory. Thus unlike -pl where maven considers all modules in your project and then build only a subpart of them, -f only build what is referenced by this project/module/pom. To do

```
mvn clean install -f maven-module-2
```

is exactly like

```
cd maven-module-2; mvn clean install
```